# How can I generate Microsoft Teams approvals using an Azure .NET Core webapp

Tags: asp.net-core, power-automate, azure-queues

I want to convert a PowerAutomate-heavy workflow using [MS Teams approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/teams/native-approvals-in-teams) to an ASP.NET Core application.

Is there a way to create approvals without the need for PowerAutomate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way currently to create approvals without using PowerAutomate.

I was still able to create a .NET app using MS Teams approvals by converting all the logic to .NET, but had to create a separate PowerAutomate workflow for generating approvals.

My basic flow is:

1. .NET pushes a message to an `approval-requests` Azure queue containing info to be displayed in the approval
2. PowerAutomate workflow has a trigger for new messages in the `approval-requests` queue, gets triggered
3. PA pops the message from the queue, parses as JSON
4. PA gathers list of people from a sharepoint/AAD group, concatenates the emails together
5. PA uses concatenated email list to start and wait for an approval
6. PA pushes result of approval to the `approval-responses` queue
7. .NET background task pops messages from the `approval-responses` and does its app logic based on the result.

[image: preview]

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=netcore-cli) is helpful for getting started with .NET background tasks. However, it mentions that the Timer class doesn't wait for previous execution to finish. Instead, I just use a new thread that calls Sleep in an infinite loop while calling a `Tick` method that handles polling and blocking execution of workflows with a positive approval result.

```cs
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace app.Services
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=netcore-cli
    public class WorkflowFulfillmentService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<WorkflowFulfillmentService> _logger;
        private readonly WorkflowClient _workflowClient;
        private CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
        private Thread _thread;

        public WorkflowFulfillmentService(
            ILogger<WorkflowFulfillmentService> logger,
            WorkflowClient workflowClient
        )
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _workflowClient = workflowClient;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting workflow fulfillment service.");
            _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
            // _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.DoWork));
            _thread.Start();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async void DoWork()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                await _workflowClient.Tick();
            }
        }


        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Stopping workflow fulfillment service.");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `Startup.cs`

```cs
            services.AddHostedService<WorkflowFulfillmentService>();
```